# Switching from O365 basic authentication to modern authentication using powershell

Tags: powershell-5.0, exchange-basicauth

I have a powershell script to get the audit logs of O365 tenants. Basically, this script will give me the users who is accessing the PowerBI platform, usability, memory consumption,etc. This is currently having the basic authentication. I need to convert the basic authentication to modern authentication in the current script. As per the current implementation,I see the registry key has been added as per the basic authentication.
I have googled and could see, I need to install the EXO V2 module and try using the Connect ExchangeOnline. But I am not sure of whether, i need to add the registry key for modern authentication? Also, it will be great if someone can help me with process flow of how to proceed in here. What are the steps , I need to follow to ensure that the modern authentication is working as expected. I have tried out all the options but I could not achieve the output. Please help me here as I am new to powerShell.

Comment: can anybody help me here?

Comment: Please provide me an update on this. I am not able to connect using Exchange-Online, although I have installed the module

Comment: The term 'Search-UnifiedAuditLog' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
This is what I get when I run the connect-ExchangeOnline